# Display a number of characters inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have an asp.net web application . in a view  i have this problem: i need to adjust the content of an element `.node`

[image: demo]

i'd like to display the  content of the node inside it.if the number of characters is big i'd like to display only the characters inside the node and delete the others characters displayed outside the node.

```
<style
.node{



}
</style>
```

So how can modify the style of the class `node` to do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
.node{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

```
.node{
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [**`text-overflow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

```
.node{
text-overflow: clip; 
}
```

This property *Clips the text*

Answer (score 0):

Use inline style in your html after you calculate the length of the node's content.

```
<%
//in your script
//get length of the node's label
//set a variable with specific style / class
%>

<div class="node" style="<% the specific style %>"><% //content %></div>
```

or even use a different class...

```
 <div class="<% the specific by size class %>"><% //content %></div>
```